# Dúvida Javascript Date() [front-end]

Tags: javascript, front-end, data, timestamp, momentjs

Estou construindo um blogue pessoal usando GitHub Pages e um aplicativo desktop con NWJS para fazer a administração back-end contudo tenho uma grande dúvida quando a apresentar datas no front-end.

Como trata-se de um site "estático" as postagens são arquivos `markdown` e seus parametros de configuração  arquivos `json`, no aplicativo desktop uso [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) para salvar o timestamp da publicação (ou edição) más não sei qual a melhor abordagem (ou método) para lidar com o timezone do usuário uma vez que a função `javascript` responsável por mostrar a quanto tempo foi realizado a publicação(edição) depende do timezone do usuário.

Ao realizar uma publicação o timestamp baseia-se no horário do meu computador (ou personalizado definindo moment.js) más usuários de um timezone diferente receberam tempos diferentes no front-end baseados em seus próprios horários.

Não estou certo de como proceder para resolver isto? Grato por qualquer ajuda ou links de referencia.

**function.js**

```js
/**
 * Time ago (UNIX)
 * @param {string|number} time
 * @return {string} human readable time elapsed
 */
function timeAgo(time){
    var round = Math.round,
        now = new Date,
        t;
    //
    let format = function(n, unit){
        let a = 'hour' == unit ? 'an' : '1';
        unit = 1 == n ? unit : (unit !== 'month' ? unit + 's' : unit);
        return (1 == n ? a : n) + ' ' + unit;
    };
    // past / future
    let diff = (time > now) ? (time - now) : (now - time);
    // just now
    if (1e3 > diff) return 'now';
    // s, m, h, d, w, m, y
    if (60 > (t = round(diff / 1e3))) return format(t, 'second');
    if (60 > (t = round(diff / 6e4))) return format(t, 'minute');
    if (24 > (t = round(diff / 3.6e+6))) return format(t, 'hour');
    if (7 > (t = round(diff / 8.64e+7))) return format(t, 'day');
    if (4.34812 > (t = diff / 6.048e+8)) return format(round(t), 'week');
    if (12 > (t = round(diff / 2.63e+9))) return format(t, 'month');
    if (10 > (t = round(diff / 3.156e+10))) return format(t, 'year');
    // decades
    return format(round(diff / 3.156e+11), 'decade');
};

let btn = document.getElementById('click');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    let now = timeAgo(1502085380495);
    let span = document.getElementById('show');
    span.innerHTML = 'Published there ' + now;
}, false);
```

```html
<button id="click">click to example</button>
<br>
<br>
<span id="show"></span>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso, vê se te ajuda, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A melhor opção para lidar com isso é armazenar a data em UTC. De acordo com a documentação do moment, a menos que você defina um timezone, a data é sempre é criada no timezone local:

> Unless you specify a time zone offset, parsing a string will create a date in the current time zone - [Moment Docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

Dessa forma, armazenando a data em UTC, quando você fizer o *parsing* da data no cliente, ela será corretamente convertida para o timezone local. Exemplo:

Armazenando (backend ou frontend):

```
//Armazena a data como String - 2017-08-07T07:34:49Z
let timestamp = moment.utc().format();
```

Apresentação da data no frontend:

```
//Realiza o parsing - 2017-08-07T04:34:49-03:00
let full_timestamp = moment("2017-08-07T07:34:49Z").format();

//07-08-2017 04:34
let formatted = moment("2017-08-07T07:34:49Z").format("DD-MM-YY HH:mm");
```